# Looking for fast method to converting boolean[] in Gray code to BigInteger and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, converters, biginteger, arbitrary-precision

For GA needed two methods:

```
BigInteger greyToBigInteger(boolean[]){...}
```

and

```
boolean[] bigIntegerToGrey(BigInteger){...}
```

For example:

```
15 ---> {true,false,false,false}
and
{true,false,false,false} --> 15
```

I don't know, how to make that very fast. Max number to convert is 10^1125, so it works more than 5 minutes for one number, if I do it, like in Wikipedia example.

Comment: If you can combine 4 booleans each together, you can make a short lookup table, resulting in a hex digit for each 4 boolean combination. Now just add the hex digit to a string builder and generate the BigInteger from the resulting hex string. Hex to BigInteger conversions are, IME, extremely fast.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I find some methods to convert BigInteger(Gray) <-->BigInteger(binary). I can use them, but I need to convert boolean[] <--> BigInteger first, but I don't sure how fast it can work.

Comment: Just collect, say 16 booleans, turn them into a 16 bit integer, shift the BigInteger(Gray) left by 16 and add the 16 bit integer. Repeat until finished. Then you just call the BigInteger(Gray) -> BigInteger(binary) code and voilà! You do know how to turn 16 booleans (in effect, 16 bits) into a 16 bit integer, right? Or how to turn a 16 bit int into 16 booleans?

Answer (score 1):

I've writen this piece of code, and it run pretty fast without any special tricks - **on my laptop machine it takes less than 2 milliseconds** to convert the given number that is less than or equal 10^1125 to gray and back:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class GrayCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // actually 10^1125 is a number with max length of 3738 bits
        int bitLength = new BigInteger("10").pow(1125).bitLength();
        System.out.println("10^1125 is a number with max bit length = " + bitLength);
        new GrayCode().test(bitLength);
    }

    private void test(int bitLength) {
        long totalTime = 0;
        long numberOfTests = 1000;

        for (int n = 0; n < numberOfTests; n++) {
            // We don't include time needed for generation of a number
            BigInteger binary = generateBigInteger(bitLength);

            // here we start measuring execution time of single conversion
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // The conversion to gray and back
            boolean[] gray = bigIntegerToGrey(binary);  
            BigInteger back = grayToBigInteger(gray);

            // we sum up the conversion times to totalTime per this test suite
            totalTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }
        System.out.println("We have run a "+numberOfTests+" tests, for a random numbers of "+bitLength+" bit length to convert to gray code and back to binary");
        System.out.println("The total execution time of this test was "+totalTime+" milliseconds, giving average convesion time of " + totalTime/1000d + " ms per single test ");

    }

    private BigInteger grayToBigInteger(boolean[] booleanGray) {
        BigInteger input = booleanToBigInteger(booleanGray);
        return grayToBinary(input);
    }

    private boolean[] bigIntegerToGrey(BigInteger binary) {
        BigInteger gray = binaryToGray(binary);
        return bigIntegerToBooleanArray(gray);
    }

    public boolean[] bigIntegerToBooleanArray(BigInteger number) {
        char[] binary = number.toString(2).toCharArray();
        boolean[] binaryBoolean = new boolean[binary.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < binary.length; n++) {
            if (binary[n] == '1') {
                binaryBoolean[n] = true;
            }
        }
        return binaryBoolean;
    }

    private BigInteger generateBigInteger(int numBits) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(numBits, rnd);
        return number;
    }

    public BigInteger booleanToBigInteger(boolean[] binary) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (boolean b : binary) {
            sb.append(b ? '1' : '0');
        }
        return new BigInteger(sb.toString(), 2);
    }

    public BigInteger binaryToGray(BigInteger num) {
        return num.xor(num.shiftRight(1));
    }

    public BigInteger grayToBinary(BigInteger num) {
        BigInteger mask;
        for (mask = num.shiftRight(1); mask.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0; mask = mask.shiftRight(1)) {
            num = num.xor(mask);
        }
        return num;
    }

}
```

the results:

```
10^1125 is a number with max bit length = 3738
We have run a 1000 tests, for a number of 3738 bit length to convert to gray code and back to binary
The total execution time of this test was 1828 milliseconds, giving average convesion time of 1.828 ms per single test
```